# Is there a better way to refresh a join table than use delete followed by insert or differential update?

Tags: mysql

When using MySQL, is there a better way to maintain a many-to-many join table than performing a `DELETE` on a primary key, followed by an `INSERT` with the current values?

For example if you have table A and B with table A_B containing two primary keys that represent the many-to-many relationship of records in A to B. Records in A_B need to be periodically updated to reflect new associations requiring some to be removed and others to be added.

I've read that in some cases its easier to calculate the differences and selectively `DELETE` unused pairs and only `INSERT` new ones, but if the data set is small that a `DELETE` on just the affected primary key, followed by repopulating it with an `INSERT` is preferable.

I can't help but think there has to be a better way than blowing it all way and filling it, or calculating the changes.

Comment: I asked this same question on Twitter [a couple of weeks ago](https://twitter.com/#!/_philBrown/status/127200662214807553). Hope you get a better response than I did :)

Comment: Good luck gaining answers from Twitter. Thats like yelling into a crowd and expecting a cogent response. Yeah, I'm just hoping that people don't read my question too superficially.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for is more of a "state" table, part of which will provide the function of a many-to-many join table.

What this state will do is keep track of all of the states of the relationships between table A and table B.  Compared to a simple many-to-many join table, you'll be able to keep historical data in this table, see who made the changed, and not delete any data at all.  You could also use this structure to make changes that will apply at a future date, with a little infrastructure.  You could also easily archive historical records at any time.

In the simplest implementation, you would have the following columns in your table A_B:

```
ID - Primary Key, could be anything.  The value isn't important
A_ID - The ID from table A
B_ID - The ID from table B
RELATIONSHIP - This is how the record from table A and table B are related.   It could be as simple as "true/false" or "listed/not-listed" or "associated/removed"
STATUS - "Current/Not-current"  or something similar.
```

All you will be doing with this table is inserting records, with a status of "Current" assuming you went with that value.  You would then have a a function triggered before insert.  The psuedo code would like something like:

```
beforeInsert (current_data) {
  find all rows where A_Id = current_data.id and b_id = current_data.id and status = 'Current'
  for each row, change status to 'Not-current' 
}
```

So, what does this get you?

**Your joins are (almost) exactly the same as a simple multi-join table**

```
SELECT A.name, B.name 
FROM A 
JOIN A_B on A.ID = A_B.A_ID and A_B.status = 'Current' and A_B.relationship = 'listed'
JOIN B on A_B.B_ID = B.id
```

**You get historical data**

you can easily see who did what when, with some audit fields, as well as the state of the relationship on a specific date. 
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
| ID  |   ID_A    |   ID_B    | Relationship |   Status    | Entered_Date | User |
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
|   1 | Company A | Product A | Listed       | Not-Current | 1-Nov        | Tom  |
|   2 | Company A | Product B | Listed       | Not-Current | 1-Nov        | Jack |
|   3 | Company B | Product A | Listed       | Current     | 1-Nov        | Tina |
|   4 | Company B | Product B | Not-Listed   | Current     | 1-Nov        | Tina |
|   5 | Company A | Product A | Not-Listed   | Current     | 2-Nov        | Tom  |
|   6 | Company A | Product B | Listed       | Current     | 2-Nov        | Tom  |
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+

**Pre-enter data**

If you changed status to "active_on" and "expires_on" you could use this to pre-enter state changes into the system.

**More**

This gives you a flexible structure to be able to extend a simple many-to-many join table, without adding a whole lot of complexity to the queries or how the join is actually working.

Comment: As I interpret it, Scott's question is not what happens when A or B get deleted but rather how to change associations between existing As and Bs.

Comment: That's correct. I don't need to worry about referential integrity, just updating associations.

Comment: So, let's say that table A was 100 car models, and table B was 100 dealerships, and table A_B was a table listing which models were associated with which dealerships.  What would you be trying to update?

Comment: (speaking on Scott's behalf): The Ford Fiesta was previously available at dealers 10, 11, 19, 36, and 50, but is now available at dealers 4, 11, 36, 68, and 92.

Comment: @LarryLustig is right. I just want to update the many-to-many relationships. On a side note, MyISAM tables don't support foreign keys, only InnoDB (and Oracle).